# Copying Cells from Last Row to Next Row

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to copy Columns D & E from the last row to the next row. Currently I am getting a Compile Error: Type Mismatch. I've been fighting this all day with different ways of going about it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub PTB()

Dim LastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
End With



Dim lastCellCoords As String: lastCellCoords = "D" & LastRow & ":E" & LastRow

Dim firstEmptyRow As Integer: firstEmptyRow = LastRow + 1
Dim firstEmptyCoords As String: firstEmptyCoords = "D" & firstEmptyRow & ":E" & firstEmptyRow

If Not LastRow Is Nothing Then
    ' Now Copy the range:
    Worksheets("Survey").Range(lastCellCoords).Copy
    ' And paste to first empty row
    Worksheets("Survey").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Else
    MsgBox ("There is no data in specified range")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `If Not LastRow Is Nothing Then`... `LastRow` can never be `Nothing`. It might be `= 1` though. There are better ways of checking if there is data in that range though, including `WorksheetFunction.CountA`.

Comment: Solved, just removed the IF statement sense I am pasting that info right before this sub.